# load mobile version of ipboard forum in webview

Tags: android, webview

How can i load the mobile version of ipboard forums?I've managed yet to load mobile versions of blogs using the following code, but it's not working with ipboard.Probably because it's using a theme for mobiles.

```
        WebView web=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.forumview); 
        web.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android");
        web.loadUrl("http://blabla.com/forum");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as useragent string: `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRG83) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1`

[Here](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/user-agent) you can see the Chrome for Android useragent strings and how they are generated.

The phone ua:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; <Android Version>; <Build Tag etc.>)
AppleWebKit/<WebKit Rev> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/<Chrome Rev> Mobile
Safari/<WebKit Rev>`

an example for the Galaxy Nexus:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; Galaxy Nexus Build/IMM76B)
AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.133 Mobile
Safari/535.19`

Comment: OK.The problem is that with your useragent string, or when i use "Android" or even when i get the useragent of my phone and then set it on setUserAgentString websites load their mobile versions as they should.But on ipBoard forums they keep loading the desktop version.

Comment: Maybe there isn't a mobile version?

Comment: There is a mobile version, but as a theme.

Comment: So, then you could add a cookie which activate the theme to get the mobile site.